# Physical size of imported sprites in Unity3d

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I was working on a game for iOS in Unity3d and after building my game and sending it to device I noticed that the actual size of installed application is terribly big (by terribly big I mean size over 2GB, lol).

I was wandering, why so? So I created test project, created scene and added to it one image with size 2048x2048. So I got project with this files:

- MySprite
- MyScene

MySprite was imported with following settings:

- **Texture Type**: Sprite
- **Sprite Mode**: Single
- **Pixels To Units**: 100
- **Filter Mode**: Point
- **Max Size**: 2048
- **Format**: Truecolor

And I even didn't forgot to uncheck overriding this settings for iOS. So, MySprite has size of 16 MB in uncompressed state. It's good. No quality loses, 32bit per pixel.

Then I created Xcode project. And found in Data folder file **sharedassets0.assets** that wights *ta-da-da* 16.1 MB! I made some research and found that this file is big because of MySprite. So... I was confused. A bit. Then I made ipa file from this Xcode project and unpacked cool-game.ipa file and again found **sharedassets0.assets** that wights *ta-da-da* 16.1 MB!

I don't like this behaviour. Why MySprite has physical size of 16 MB? I understand, that in uncompressed state in memory it will take 16 MB anyway. But I would like to have compressed file on device and uncompress it in runtime. Because I don't like to have application with size = 16 MB * 100 :)

So, is it possible to ask Unity3d to compress images on build?

P. S. I am using OS X 10.9.3, Unity3d v.4.5. I have Unity3d Pro, but not iOS Pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found next solution.

I put all images I need to be physically light into Resources folder with `.bytes` extension. Then I load them via

```
var binImage = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(imagePathInResourcesFolder);
myTexture2D.LoadImage(binImage.bytes);
```

If you need Sprite from `Texture2D` you can always use `Sprite.Create()` function.

It's good for me because I can easily load images and unload them to free memory usage. But this solution has great drawback. Without any Unity3d extensions we loose usual Unity workflow. That's sad. But it's only solution I found working.

P. S. actually you can use WWW class to load images. But currently I prefer working with Resources.

P. P. S. remember that Unity3d include everything it can work with from Resources folder into build.